# getting turtles to consider other turtle's variables

Tags: netlogo

I am new to Netlogo  and have become stumped with a problem.

I have written a model where one breed of turtles (wombats) randomly chose to move-to different burrows (a second breed of turtles). However, I now wish to make it so that the quality (represented by a number) of the burrow currently on the same patch as a wombat influences the probability of the wombat moving to a different burrow. I had envisaged this to look similar to:

```
ask wombats[  
if random-float 100 >= burrow-fidelity * ( quality one-of burrows burrows-here / 2)
  [move-to one-of burrows with [not any? wombats-here]]
 ]
```

however this does not work.
Is there anyway that I make the wombat report the size of the burrow currently sharing the same patch (there is only ever one burrow per a patch) and then make the wombat incorporate the reported value into the above equation where "quality one-of burrows burrows-here" is?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To report the value of another agent's variable, use the [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) keyword:

```
[ quality ] of one-of burrows-here
```